# How can I pass a class structure (in order to pattern match) & a template as method parameters

Tags: scala, class, types, playframework, parameter-passing

OK. So I have two actions in my controller (using **Play 2.5** & **Scala 2.11.11**). Both make call requests to different external APIs and follow the same pattern:

```
  def getSunResponse(lat: Double, lng: Double) = Action.async { request =>

    sw.makeServiceCall(lat,lng).map { response =>

      response match {
        case JsSuccess(r: SunInfo, path: JsPath) => Ok(views.html.temp1(r))
        case e: JsError => Ok(s"Errors: ${JsError.toJson(e).toString()}")
      }

    }
  }
```

..and..

```
  def getMoonResponse(lat: Double, lng: Double) = Action.async { request =>

    sw.makeServiceCall(lat,lng).map { response =>

      response match {
        case JsSuccess(r: MoonInfo, path: JsPath) => Ok(views.html.temp2(r))
        case e: JsError => Ok(s"Errors: ${JsError.toJson(e).toString()}")
      }

    }
  }
```

As they have just two differences between them; the *class pattern* being matched `SunInfo` & `MoonInfo` (*case classes* referenced in another file) and the template in which successful responses are passed into `views.html.temp1` & `views.html.temp2` - I would prefer to eliminate needless repetition and pass these values within the parameters of a new *method* which replaces the need for both of these.

So to clarify I am looking to pass a *class* and a *template* (which can accept the successful result as a parameter). Currently I am having some difficulty understanding what *types* they would be passed as in the *function signature* and how they would be referenced in the *method body*. I tried `c: Class[_]` as a parameter in the *function signature* and `classOf[c]` but this doesn't work of course as it refers to an *object* rather than a class structure.

Any guidance as to how to pass these two parameters is most welcome right now. Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

apologies if I'm not answering your question...  I don't know Play, so I'm not clear on what request and response need...  but when you ask for "a new method which replaces the need for both of these"...  I think about something like this...

```
trait CelestialBodyInfo
class SunInfo extends CelestialBodyInfo
class MoonInfo extends CelestialBodyInfo


def getResponse[T <: CelestialBodyInfo](lat: Double, lng: Double) = Action.async { request =>

  sw.makeServiceCall(lat,lng).map { response =>

    response match {
      case JsSuccess(r: T, path: JsPath) => r match {
        case s: SunInfo  => Ok(views.html.temp1(s))
        case m: MoonInfo => Ok(views.html.temp2(m))
      }
      case e: JsError => Ok(s"Errors: ${JsError.toJson(e).toString()}")
    }

  }
}
```

now you can call it like...

```
getResponse[SunInfo](lat, lon)
getResponse[MoonInfo](lat, lon)
```

or if you don't need to know when you call the function, and the request gets the right response automatically...  something like this?

```
def getResponse(lat: Double, lng: Double) = Action.async { request =>

  sw.makeServiceCall(lat,lng).map { response =>

    response match {
      case JsSuccess(r: CelestialBodyInfo, path: JsPath) => r match {
        case s: SunInfo  => Ok(views.html.temp1(s))
        case m: MoonInfo => Ok(views.html.temp2(m))
      }
      case e: JsError => Ok(s"Errors: ${JsError.toJson(e).toString()}")
    }

  }
}
```

**EDIT** - responding to comment

could be something else going on here bc of Play that I don't get...  but that error message, in the general case, would mean that SunInfo is not a subtype of CelestialBodyInfo...  which it needs to be based on the type bounds on type T.

example that creates the same error message

```
trait A {
  def x: Int
}

class B(val x: Int) extends A // class B is subtype of A 
class C(val x: Int)           // class C is NOT a subtype of A 

// f requires an arg that is a subtype of A 
def f[T <: A](t: T) = t.x


f[B](new B(5))  // Int = 5 
f[C](new C(5))  // error: type arguments [C] do not conform to method f's type parameter bounds [T <: A]
```

So when I see that error, my guess is that SunInfo isn't a subtype of CelestialBodyInfo, but it's hard to say what else could be going on.

Comment: Thanks and sorry for the delay in responding - I have been testing. Unfortunately neither of these techniques work. For the 1st; calling it like this `getResponse[SunInfo](-33.8830, 151.2167)(request)` causes this error ***type arguments [models.SunInfo] do not conform to method getResponse's type parameter bounds [T <: JsonController.this.CelestialBodyInfo]***. And the 2nd doesn't recognise the differences in the classes with the pattern match so only outputs the `SunInfo` template.

Comment: response in edit above...  apologies if that doesn't help you out.

Comment: Thanks for your edit. `CelestialBodyInfo` is extended by both `SunInfo` and `MoonInfo` so I really don't see why this is error is coming out

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```scala
def getSunOrMoonResponse(sunOrMoon: String,lat: Double,lng: Double) = 
  Action.async{ request =>
      sunOrMoon match {
        case "sun" => getResponse[SunInfo](new SunSW,lat,lng)(r => views.html.temp1(r))
        case "moon" => getResponse[MoonInfo](new MoonSW,lat,lng)(r => views.html.temp2(r))
      }
  }

protected def getResponse[T](sw: SW[T],lat: Double,lng: Double)(template: T => HtmlFormat.Appendable): Future[Result] = {
  sw.makeServiceCall(lat,lng).map{
    case JsSuccess(r: T,path) => Ok(template(r))
    case e: JsError => Ok(s"Errors: ${JsError.toJson(e).toString()}")
  }
}

trait SW[+T] {
  def makeServiceCall(lat: Double,lng: Double): Future[JsResult[T]]
}

class SunSW extends SW[SunInfo] {
  override def makeServiceCall(lat: Double, lng: Double):Future[JsResult[SunInfo]] = ???
}
class MoonSW extends SW[MoonInfo] {
  override def makeServiceCall(lat: Double, lng: Double): Future[JsResult[MoonInfo]] = ???
}
```

Here I assumed that the sw that gets SunInfo and the one that get MoonInfo adhere to the same interface.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I see what you're saying but it doesn't feel quite right. 1) sending a string to differentiate the class structures. 2) repeating case results, e.g. `getResponse[MoonInfo](new MoonSW,lat,lng)(r => views.html.temp2(r))`. 3) passing a template as a parameter.

Comment: answering your questions: 1) well I saw you are inside a controller. usually which one you want to is either expressed as varying route OR same route with varying route parameter which is usually a string. I only assumed you were going for the latter. you may implement it  however you like.

Comment: 2) the ```protected def getResponse``` method is all about encapsulating all the parts that could possibly vary. it's not repetition if your feeding it with different arguments  in each case.

Comment: 3) it's the same as number 2 answer. template is a varying part which you have to pass manually for each case